# I want to detect guns in an image. What is the proper steps to do object detection (for gun) given an image with so many objects in the background?

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, object-detection

I am new to object detection and very confused how to start the basic step.I want to do object detection in an image.
Given an image, do I first need to detect all objects in that particular image (that includes car, houses, trees, etc in a background) and if a gun is also detected in that  image, we can classify them as gun or not gun?

Answer (score 0):

IF your task is to detect only guns there is no point in training a model in detecting all the other things in the image, you can start with something as simple as harr-cascade or you can take a pretrained model(resnet, Yolo or something else) on imagenet dataset (as it has guns) and fine-tune it on the data set that you have( this is called transfer learning).

Comment: Thank you Sir. Then, for what purpose are we using for e.g., haar-cascade here ? And after using haar-cascade, further what do we do next?

Comment: haar cascade gives you features and you can train an SVM or any other classifier for detecting if the image has a gun or not. for object detection, you can check out this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hPCTwxF0qf4&t=183s